# Parsing Schema got error when using PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, wsdl

I 'm trying to use PHP SoapClient to consume eBay web service. Just following the eBay official sample:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaysvc.wsdl');
```

I get an error as below:

> SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected in simpleType in E:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\system\application\libraries\Ebaysvc.php:102 Stack trace: #0

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this url for the wsdl http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/753/eBaySvc.wsdl

I don't knew why the changed the url. Thank to Pakistan for that Post http://www.adeelsarfaraz.com/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-soap-error-parsing-schema-unexpected-in-sequence-error/